# How to format shell commands run from Dired?

Tags: dired, shell

I want to execute a formatted shell command on a file from within Dired. I am aware that I can use `dired-do-shell-command` to run a shell command on a selected file file by entering

```
! <command>
```

to run

```
<command> file
```

Ideally I want to run

```
! <command> file <additional-arguments>
```

In other words I want to be able to specify where in the command file appears. I tried running

```
! <command> {} <additional-arguments>
```

and reading the doc for `dired-do-shell-command`, but neither of those gave me the solution to achieve this.

Comment: The docstring does say how to do that.  Maybe it could be more clear/explicit on that.

Comment: Now that jue pointed it out I realize it. What put me off was that that the infostring used the term file list whereas I had my mind fixed on an individual file. Therefore i disregarded that part of the infostring as unrelated to my issue. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add your parameters to the command prompt, separated by space, without any placeholder for filenames.
To construct commands like `ls -l <file>`, just enter `ls -l`.

---

**OR**: the interface supports the placeholders `*` and `?`.
Where `?` means call command with one marked file only, in a loop;
and `*` means call with all marked files.
Read more at [masteringemacs.org](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/dired-shell-commands-find-xargs-replacement)

Example: (`ls` would be your `<command>` **and** `-l` would be your `<additional-arguments>`).
You could  enter `ls * -l` as command for example to run `ls <files> -l` once (with all marked files at once).
Or you could enter `ls ? -l` to run `ls <file> -l` for every single file.

---

*Edit:* dired-do-shell-command help string:

> Signature
>   (dired-do-shell-command COMMAND &optional ARG FILE-LIST)
>
> Documentation
>   ...
>   If there is a * in COMMAND, surrounded by
>   whitespace, this runs COMMAND just once with the entire file list
>   substituted there.
>
> If there is no *, but there is a ? in COMMAND, surrounded by
>   whitespace, this runs COMMAND on each file individually with the file
>   name substituted for ?.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. I gave you an upvote, but it does not show up because I am a new user.